# I would like to combine two formulas to either do one or the other formula

Tags: google-sheets

I don't know how to explain this, but I was trying to get a cell to fill in with a certain number from one cell, I got that one to work, but now I need to add another formula to that same cell.

So I made a sheet that takes ones monthly sales from previous month and you can specify how much of any increase in percentage you want to set as a goal. Then it breaks down that total into 4 weeks and specifies how much is needed everyday to hit that goal. The problem now is some months don't have that same amount of days and I basically want the few days that aren't for that month to be blank, instead of filling in the amount for those days when they don't exist. I currently have a formula in one of the cells and I need that to stay there and also have another formula work as well.

This is the formula I have in cell V5- =IF (R11=0, SUM (S11), SUM (S11). I would like to add a formula that says if cell U5 is empty then make the cell blank, but if not, then it needs to return the value from the formula I wrote above. The same thing goes for the following cells, U6, and U7. I was trying to use ISBLANK, but I'm not sure how to use this correctly. I just would like to have the remaining cells to be blank if the month isn't 31 days. Like February only has 28 days and I don't want the sheet to have values in the cells that would correspond for the extra days other months have. I've attached a pic so anyone can get an idea of what I'm working with. Sales Goal Sheet:
[image: Sales Goal Sheet]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: What do you mean with an example of desired result? I Specified above what I want the result to be. I've also attached a pic of the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if cell U5 is empty then make the cell blank, but if not, then it needs to return the value from the formula

```
=IF(U5="";;S11)
```

Comment: do i add that that formula to the existing formula or do I add the formula where the S11 is? Why is S11 in the formula you wrote? I want V5:V7 to be blank if the cells with the dates to the left are blank. I'm sorry, I just get so confused with this stuff.

Comment: I see now. I just put in that formula in and it does exactly what I want. Thank you so much. I can't believe it was that easy. I thought it would have been some really complicated. I was hoping you might have a solution for something else on this sheet. Seems like it would be easy but I can't find anything that will do this. It might have to be a script perhaps. I was wondering if there's a way I can put in the 1st date in the 1st cell and then the sheet automatically fills in the dates in the specific cells for that month. Otherwise I have to enter all the dates cell by cell manually.

Comment: yes, that possible too (without script). would be easier if you would share a copy of your sheet

Comment: How can I share the file on here?

Comment: in a top right corner of your sheet there is a Share button. there you select "change to anyone with link" and then you just copy-paste the url address here

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lnAPxyRHtvW38OKV1KoWi_Nq9kAVA5SqYy5ifdGpihM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your help. Is there any way I can leave a master copy of this sheet with blank dates? I use a master and make copies of it to make a separate sheet for each employee.

Comment: Actually never mind. It will work just like this. When I make a copy, it will already have the dates populated. Thanks again for your help. Really appreciate it. Check your PayPal.